# Leads to detect rare events in human related multi-variable time series

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, anomaly-detection, rare-events

I am currently working on a subject and struggling to find a way to tackle it.

Ok, so, let's say I want to **predict** whenever a **human** is going to **faint** in a **rollercoaster**. I have multi-variables time series data for each "run". We have both rollercoaster related data (acceleration, height ...) and human related data (BPM, spO2 ...).
We have labeled datas for fainting runs, we know which try and when the subject fainted. Unfortunately, this event doesn't happen often (about 20 times in 1700 runs so a bit more than 1%).

So basically, I have :

- Extremely rare events.
- Multi variables time series (human and sensors data).
- Low number of labeled datas (20 out or 1700)

I have been doing research on anomalies detection in time series but what I found was mostly about  detecting sensors anomalies and not human correlated anomalies.

I've seen people using [LSTM AutoEncoders](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-autoencoder-for-extreme-rare-event-classification-in-keras-ce209a224cfb), [Regression Trees](https://neptune.ai/blog/anomaly-detection-in-time-series), apply FFT on data ...
But none of these seems to fit my problem. Again, I am not trying to detect sensors anomalies (like unexpected noise/weird values) but more human/medical related anomalies.

I was initially going for a CNN1D into LSTM classifier and try to predict through classification for each point but with such a low % of positive labels (~21 000 timesteps out of ~12 000 000 timesteps), I've been told it won't learn anything.

So here I am, willing to discuss about this subject, if any of you guys have an idea, a lead on how to tackle this problem, feel free.

Comment: Do you have reasons to believe that this is in fact predictable (in general, and given the data that you have)? Can you see any patterns? How well can a human do the task?

Comment: Is the goal to determine whether the human will occur, or when?

Comment: What is the dominant axis of variability - the subjects, or the ride?

Comment: @JonNordby, 1) We are currently trying to figure out if it's predictable, we don't know for sure yet. Trained humans can do the task with a good accuracy. They use face video from the subject mixed with the data to predict fainting. (video is exploited by other leads, we focus on sensor data here). We can't figure out any patterns using sensor data only yet but are working on it. 2) We would try to determine if it will occur first. If we manage to do so, then to predict it. 3)The dominant axis of variability here is the subject, rides are always the same.

Comment: Very interesting. How long in advance can humans (reliably) predict the fainting? If one can get a number for that, it may be possible to only look around that time-frame before the fainting event, which could help narrow the data-analysis considerably

Comment: That's a great idea to explore. We don't have that number but I'd say from what I've seen that they can predict in the second before fainting really happens. We wanted to keep the whole data so the model can learn about 'normal behavior' but I guess we don't need that much data and it causes the unbalance.

Comment: Then I would plot the 10 seconds before for the 20 cases where people fainted, versus a small sample of the cases where people did not faint, say 20-50 at a time. And then if you see any patterns that seem to distinguish the groups, try to make simple features that describe these.

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you for the advices :)

Comment: How did it go @Jules?

Comment: I've looked around the crucial moment, but couldn't find any recurrent pattern. Talked as well with specialist to try to get a better understanding of their way of predicting. We're now working on doing a annotating session to get more quality data and hope for the best !

Comment: Best of luck! Hoping to see a paper some day :)